Dynamic QR with payTM in java springboot application
I'm using java code in https://business.paytm.com/docs/api/create-qr-code-api/
to create dynamic QR code using payTM.
However I'm getting
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset.
Could someone help regarding this?

I suggest you put your version of the code here as reference in case there is something different
